# confusion in the angle between the two vectors when calculating their cross product.

Tags: vectors

the formula of cross product is A⃗×B⃗=|A⃗||B⃗|sinθncap
the formula of magnitude of cross product is |A⃗×B⃗|=|A⃗||B⃗|sinθ
In many of the definition of cross product, I have seen the θ(angle between the two vector) is in the range of 0≤θ≤π.

The angle between the two vector can be measured in two ways, clockwise and anti-clockwise. The clockwise wise measurement is generally taken to be negative and the anti-clockwise wise measurement is generally taken to be positive.

How can the θ always lie in the 0≤θ≤π.for example, take two vectors
A⃗=1icap
and
B⃗=-1jcap
. The angle between these vectors could be measured -π/2 and π/2 if we measure it clockwise and anticlockwise respectively. How can the -π/2 incorporated in the range 0≤θ≤π.

Is it the case that we ignore clockwise measurement when measuring the angle between vector or is it the case that the which is present in the formula |A⃗×B⃗|=|A⃗||B⃗|sinθ is just the magnitude of the angle present between the two vector and direction(clockwise or anti-clockwise) is not considered(θ
=|angle between the vectors|)

Answer (score 1):

Clockwise and anti-clockwise do not make much sense if you are in three dimensions. It always depends on from which side you are looking at your two vectors. You thus only measure the absolute value of the angle. Also note that a magnitude has to be non-negative, i.e. $\sin\theta$ must be $\geq 0$. This is exactly the case when $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

Comment: By absolute value of angle, do you mean magnitude of angle (which is always positive)?

Comment: @hsdfasd Yes, indeed.

Comment: "You thus only measure the absolute value of the angle"                                                                                                                                         But If I calculate the dot product of the vectors I earlier mentioned, then A⃗.B⃗=|A||B|cosθ=>0=cosθ=>θ=±π/2. Should I only consider θ=π/2 because that is the absolute value of the angle and reject θ=-π/2

Comment: @hsdfasd That depends on whether you are in two or three dimensions. In two dimensions it can make sense to talk about clockwise and anti-clockwise orientation. In three dimensions it does not as it is not clear which is which. Either way, the dot product doesn't tell you anything about the orientation of the two vectors. You can only infer the absolute value of the angle from it.

Comment: But two vector whose tail coincide are co planar. Couldn't the clockwise or anticlockwise orientation with respect to one vector be  decided on that common plane?

Comment: @hsdfasd No because that depends on from which side of the plane you are observing the situation.

Comment: But generally, a line which is in the Cartesian plane is often represented such that it makes certain angle with positive direction of x-axis in anti-clockwise or clockwise orientation.  For example, the line x-y=0 is generally represented by considering anti-clockwise or clockwise orientation with respect to x-axis in the Cartesian plane (it makes π/4 with positive direction of x-axis in anti-clockwise direction). How is that possible, since the clockwise or anti-clockwise orientation depends on from which side of the plane we are observing the plane?

Comment: @hsdfasd In 2D there is a implicit convention that you are looking from above onto the plane and not from below. In other sciences you sometimes see the opposite convention, that is, the $y$-axis points downwards. You could of course make a similar convention in 3D, but it is not customary and you would have to change your formulas accordingly as, for example, your formula for the magnitude of the cross product would fail.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitud of the cross product is not not a polar description of the angular distance, but as a geometric property related to these two vectors. The geometric description of it is that the magnitud of the cross product is the area of the triangle formed with the vectors, so the angle considered must be between $0$ and $\pi$.